# Dynamically built SiteMapPath in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, navigation, sitemap, sitemappath

I'm trying to build a dynamic site map on my site using SiteMapPath.

Should be like this:

```
Home > Products > %product_name% > Prices
```

where `%product_name%` is set dynamically in the runtime, depending on the user's choice.

I've read many articles on the theme and choose this http://harriyott.com/2007/03/adding-dynamic-nodes-to-aspnet-site.aspx. It dynamically changes the `web.sitemap` XML file. The problem is that it still builds the sitemap only once in the beginning and then uses it on each page.

How can I make it to rebuild on each loaded page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

Right click on your project "add new item" then choose "Site Map",
it will have an XML structure that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

     <siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >

       <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Home " description="">

         <siteMapNode url="~/the page URL" title="Products"  description="" >

             <siteMapNode url="~/the page URL" title=" %product_name%"  description="" >

                 <siteMapNode url="~/the page URL" title="Prices"  description="" />

             </siteMapNode >

         </siteMapNode >

       </siteMapNode >

     <sitemap>
```

** adding description for each node is optional.

Now you need to place it where you want, so you add this code in the HTML side of the     page:

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server">

<CurrentNodeStyle CssClass="Some class" />

   <PathSeparatorTemplate>

      <img runat="server" alt="" src="an image to separate between nodes" height="5" width="5" />

   </PathSeparatorTemplate>

</asp:SiteMapPath>
```

---

Of course you have two pages - one for product and one for prices.

To assign Tile dynamically for some node in the SiteMap; add this code in the Prices Page:

1) In the page load:

```
SiteMap.SiteMapResolve += new SiteMapResolveEventHandler(SiteMap_SiteMapResolve);
```

2) Add this function in the same page (prices page):

```
 SiteMapNode SiteMap_SiteMapResolve(object sender, SiteMapResolveEventArgs e)
{
    SiteMapNode currentNode = SiteMap.CurrentNode.Clone(true);
    SiteMapNode tempNode = currentNode;

    tempNode.ParentNode.Title = "Change the Product name";
    tempNode.ParentNode.Url = "Change the Product url";

    return currentNode;
}
```

As you can see you can manipulate the parent Node as you want, change the title, the url, etc. I think you want to change the url too; for example: "product.aspx?ID=blah"

Comment: in that case, the %product_name% value is constant, and i need it to be set in the runtime, when Product.aspx loads and the selected product is known

Comment: What about something like for my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892575/how-to-set-up-a-breadcrumb-in-an-asp-net-page. I have the look & feel set up and just need to add an LI to my UL each time :)

Answer (score 1):

Great!
In case of someone wants the same in vb here is the code:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    AddHandler SiteMap.SiteMapResolve, AddressOf Me.SiteMap_SiteMapResolve

End Sub

Private Function SiteMap_SiteMapResolve(sender As Object, e As SiteMapResolveEventArgs) As SiteMapNode
    Dim currentNode As SiteMapNode = SiteMap.CurrentNode.Clone(True)
    Dim tempNode As SiteMapNode = currentNode

    tempNode.ParentNode.Title = "Change the Product name"
    tempNode.ParentNode.Url = "Change the Product url"

    Return currentNode
End Function
```