# SiteMapPath: change the title and link of the last link in chain

Tags: asp.net, sitemappath

Hi
Can you advise please any solution? 
I have a SiteMapPath control and instead of default functionality like

```
Home > Accounts > User Account
```

where "User Account" refers to ~/UserAccount.aspx

I would like to overwrite the last node to show info about a current user, i.e.:

```
Home > Accounts > John White
```

and "John White" refers to ~/UserAccount.aspx?id=111 ?

Comment: Which provider are you using?

Comment: standard xmlSiteMapProvider. Probably I should inherit from it and add some functionality to support extended .sitemap syntax.

Comment: follow the link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757742/dynamically-built-sitemappath-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you have to inherit from the `XmlSiteMapProvider` and override its `BuildSiteMap` method. In here you can manipulate any nodes you want at runtime, which will then show up in your `SiteMapPath` control.

```
public class MySiteMapProvider : XmlSiteMapProvider
{
   ...

   public override SiteMapNode BuildSiteMap()
   {
     var node = base.BuildSiteMap();
     var userAccountsNode = this.FindUserAccountsNode(node);

     userAccountsNode.ReadOnly = false;
     userAccountsNode.Title = ...;
     userAccountsNode.Url = ...;
     userAccountsNode.ReadOnly = true;

     return node;
   }
}
```