# Preserving query string params in parent breadcrumb (SiteMapPath)

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm looking for a way to preserve query string parameters when navigating back up the stack using the standard `<asp:SiteMapPath>` implementation.

For simplicity, suppose I have a `Animal > Breed` page stack:

```
 <siteMapNode url="~/Animal.aspx" title="Animal" >
    <siteMapNode url="~/Breed.aspx" title="Breed"/>  
</siteMapNode>
```

I navigate to `Animal.aspx?type=Dog` and select a dog breed to navigate to `Breed.aspx?type=Bulldog`

On `Breed.aspx` I have the correct breadcrumb `Animal > Breed` but the `Animal` url is just `Animal.aspx`. How can I get the Animal link to be the parent/previous page `Animal.aspx?type=Dog`?

In this simplistic example I realise I could feasibly add all the animal type as separate nodes with their relevant type. My actual setup is more complicated and requires ids to be read from the a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757742/dynamically-built-sitemappath-in-asp-net) I have added the follow to the detail page (Breed.aspx in the example)

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
            if (!IsPostBack)
                SiteMap.SiteMapResolve += new SiteMapResolveEventHandler(SiteMap_SiteMapResolve);
     }

     SiteMapNode SiteMap_SiteMapResolve(object sender, SiteMapResolveEventArgs e){
            SiteMapNode currentNode = SiteMap.CurrentNode.Clone(true);
            
            currentNode.ParentNode.Url += "?type=" + this.Breed.AnimalType;

            return currentNode;
        }
```

**EDIT**

<strike>Seems to work well</strike>

The url is updated however I use CurrentNode a lot in my menu controls navigating up and down the site map. When I clone I lose sibling information breaking my menus.

I either need to find a way of cloning which preserves the entire sitemap or find another way of amending the ParentNode.Url

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the parameter to whatever link the user is to click on to navigate...

So you would use something like

```
mytype = Request.QueryString["type"];
```

to get the value, the apply that to the link...

```
mylink.NavigateURL = "animal.aspx?type="+mytype;
```

I did this outside of the editor, so you'll need to watch for syntax errors...

Here's some documentation...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I was hoping for something a lot less manual, I'd have to do this explicitly on each page requiring it. My breadcrumb is also in a master page so hard to get at from page level.