# Alternative to SiteMapNode.Clone(true) which includes siblings

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sitemap

I'd like an alternative to `SiteMap.CurrentNode.Clone(true)` which preserves both parents, siblings and children. I'd like to then be able to traverse the SiteMap as if I was accessing the SiteMap directly.

The original problem is listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281654/preserving-query-string-params-in-parent-breadcrumb-sitemappath/21314262#21314262)

On a particular page I use `SiteMap.SiteMapResolve` to edit the parent of CurrentNode. This breaks my code elsewhere which navigates up the stack and then access all ChildNodes at the required level:

```
SiteMapNode c = System.Web.SiteMap.CurrentNode;    
if (jumpsRequired < 0) {
       while (jumpsRequired < 0)
       {
            c = c.ParentNode;
            jumpsRequired++;
       }
}
return c.HasChildNodes ? c.ChildNodes.Cast<SiteMapNode>() : new List<SiteMapNode>();
```

Because I am cloning CurrentNode on `SiteMap.SiteMapResolve` ChildNodes.Count <= 1 as the clone doesn't copy the siblings.